# How do I get Haml to work with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, haml

I am trying to get Haml to work with my Ruby on Rails project. I am new to Ruby on Rails and I really like it. However, when I attempt to add an `aplication.html.haml` or `index.html.haml` for a view, I just receive errors.

I am using NetBeans as my IDE.

Comment: What are the errors? Do you have the HAML plugin installed?

Answer (score 88):

### Haml with Rails 3

For Rails 3 all you need to do is add `gem "haml", '3.0.25'` to your `Gemfile`. No need to install plugin or run `haml --rails .`.

Just:

```
$ cd awesome-rails-3-app.git
$ echo 'gem "haml"' >> Gemfile
```

And you're done.

Comment: Add echo 'gem "haml-rails", :group => :development' >> Gemfile to use haml for scaffolding as default option.

Comment: and also `bundle` I presume

Answer (score 61):

The answers above are spot-on. You just need to put `gem 'haml'` in your `Gemfile`.

One other tip that was not mentioned: to have rails generators use `haml` instead of `erb`, add the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :haml

  # you can also specify a different test framework or ORM here
  # g.test_framework  :rspec
  # g.orm             :mongoid
end
```

Comment: Alternatively to editing `application.rb`, you can add `gem 'haml-rails'` to the development group in `Gemfile`. That will also take care of the generators.

Comment: this is equivalent to `config.generators.template_engine :haml` although the do block is nice if you want to customize a number of generators.  And to reiterate, if you use `gem 'haml-rails'` it should solve this problem without needing a line of code in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 37):

First, **install haml** as a gem in bundler by adding this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "haml"
```

Run `bundle install`, then make sure your views are named with a ***.html.haml** extension.  For example:

```
`-- app
    `-- views
        |-- layouts
        |   `-- application.html.haml
        `-- users
            |-- edit.html.haml
            |-- index.html.haml
            |-- new.html.haml
            `-- show.html.haml
```

Comment: If you have erb templates already go ahead and rename them .html.haml. At the top of the file tell haml to use the erb filter by putting :erb at the top of the file. Then you can slowly convert your templates. More on filters by visiting.

http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/docs/rdoc/classes/Haml.html

Comment: Why is it important to end with .html.haml and not just .haml?

Comment: mathee, It's Rails convention.  `name.mime.format` (e.g. show.html.erb, show.xml.builder, show.html.haml)

Answer (score 25):

Add haml to your Gemfile:

```
gem "haml"
```

If you want to use the scaffold-functions too, add haml-rails within your development-group:

```
gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development
```

Don't forget to run:

```
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 11):

Before trying to use haml in your rails application, you can verify that the command line executable is installed correctly:

```
$ haml
%p 
  %span Hello World!
```

Then press CTRL-D and you should see:

```
<p>
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: nice...that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 10):

First, make sure you have the HAML gem.

```
gem list --local | grep haml
```

If haml doesn't show up in the list, then do this:

```
sudo gem install haml
```

Then do this from your project directory:

```
# cd ../
# haml --rails <yourproject>
```

That should install everything you need, and the HAML views should stop complaining and parse correctly.

Comment: Be mindful that for Rails 3, `haml --rails` is no longer needed. See my answer for Rails 3 howto.

Comment: Please, avoid using `sudo` when you install gems.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an old question but I think the answer is using haml-rails at https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you installed haml, but you haml doesn't start. try

```
sudo ln haml /usr/bin/
```

in the bin directory of your haml gem

for some reason this didn't happen automatically on my ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Pow](http://pow.cx/) you will need to restart it also. Ideally you are using [powder](http://rubygems.org/gems/powder) (gem install powder), because then you can just run this at the terminal

```
$ powder restart
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add `haml` gem into your `Gemfile`