# how to use haml in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I want to use haml in rails 3 project.

Now how to start?
How to cofig it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just follow the instruction on the [HAML Reference page](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plugin)

In short:

> For Rails 3, instead add the following
>   line to the Gemfile: gem "haml"
>
> Once it’s installed, all view files
>   with the ".html.haml" extension will
>   be compiled using Haml.

Comment: If you want to use the scaffold-function with haml too, you will need the rails-haml in development. gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development

Answer (score 3):

Add haml to your Gemfile

```
gem "haml"
```

If you want to use the scaffold-functions too, add html-rails within your development-group

```
gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do follow this tutorial: where you customise the generators:
http://paulbarry.com/articles/2010/01/13/customizing-generators-in-rails-3

or just follow this simple way to do it
original post: [How do I get Haml to work with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99211/how-do-i-get-haml-to-work-with-rails)

First, install haml as a plugin

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/nex3/haml.git
```

Then, Make sure your views are named with a *.html.haml extension. For example:

```
`-- app
    `-- views
        |-- layouts
        |   `-- application.html.haml
        `-- users
            |-- edit.html.haml
            |-- index.html.haml
            |-- new.html.haml
            `-- show.html.haml
```

(Note: You could instead install haml as a gem, but for the sake of simplicity, let's just assume using it as a plugin is the best bet.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I like this tutorial - gives all the steps from the ground up. 
http://screencasts.org/episodes/using-haml-with-rails-3