# Alternative HTML syntax

Tags: html, syntax

It's a subjective question but don't you think the following HTML syntax would make more sense?

```
<div #id .class1 .class2><!-- content --></div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="id" class="class1 class2"><!-- content --></div>
```

Comment: How would that work with XHTML?

Comment: @Chris: Exactly my thoughts. Or with style sheets other than CSS. Or with other languages that use CSS, such as SVG ;-)

Comment: It's not really a subjective question - there are some very objective reasons as to why you shouldn't do this

Comment: @Yi Jiang, there are but there are also objective reasons (maybe not as many) as to why you should do it (such as readability). That makes the question subjective.

Comment: I added something I just found in my answer. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might be that it makes more sense to someone who authors only HTML and CSS. However, bear in mind that

- CSS was invented much later than HTML
- HTML is largely backwards-compatible; you can still view current web pages with ancient browsers and there is no need to change that
- Your proposed syntax is incompatible with XML. Therefore you're throwing out all XHTML folks
- Furthermore, do you want to change other languages too that rely on CSS for styling, e.g. SVG (again, XML, therefore incompatible)?

I agree, for a very narrow purpose, it might be a beneficial change, but when viewing at this from a broader angle, I doubt you'll see much improvement, only pain. You can of course use a preprocessor to write your HTML this way and convert it to the actual thing.

You may also want to take a look at other languages who convert into HTML, such as [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/).

If you are content with just typing something similar to what you have proposed, then [Zen-Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) might be an option for you. Quoting:

> Zen Coding is an editor plugin for high-speed HTML, XML, XSL (or any other structured code format) coding and editing. The core of this plugin is a powerful abbreviation engine which allows you to expand expressions—similar to CSS selectors—into HTML code. For example:
>
> ```
> div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a
> ```
>
> ... can be expanded into:
>
> ```
> <div id="page">
>     <div class="logo"></div>
>     <ul id="navigation">
>         <li><a href=""></a></li>
>         <li><a href=""></a></li>
>         <li><a href=""></a></li>
>         <li><a href=""></a></li>
>         <li><a href=""></a></li>
>     </ul>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Not really. Attributes in HTML are general, CSS only builds on top of them. HTML itself has no notion of "ids" or "classes", only attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You might enjoy using [HAML](https://haml.info) (with any of [these implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml#Implementations)):

```
%body
    #header
        %h1 BoBlog
        %h2 Bob's Blog
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Looks very interesting. Do you know of any popular project that uses HAML?

Comment: @Emanuil I'm not sure if there's a definitive list, the fact that it's been ported to several different platforms and has widespread editor support would seem to indicate it's widely used.

Comment: thanks again. I'm definitely interested in the concept. I'll look more into it as soon as I have a little more time.

Comment: @Emanuil Rails does support HAML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99211/how-do-i-get-haml-to-work-with-rails

Answer (score 2):

That might work for the example you provide, but how would you notate the following?

```
<a id="my-link" href="http://example.com" rel="external" target="_parent" class="complex" title="click here for no good reason">My Link</a>
```

HTML has specific attribute names so that you can work with key/value pairs (with the possible exception of boolean attributes such as `checked`).  If you take away the keys, the values become ambiguous and it is too hard to see what property should adopt which value.

Comment: All other attributes would work the classic way - `attr="value"`.

Comment: That would then be `<a #my-link href='http://example.com' rel='external' target='_parent' .complex title='click here for no good reason'>My Link</a>` – I didn't understand his idea that he wants a single-character shortcut for every conceivable attribute there is.

Comment: Phil: I guess, because modern web pages with extensive styling put a class or id on nearly any element in the page.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler, `class` and `id` are much used, they work on every tag and CSS has made them easily associated with the `#` and the `.` symbols.

Comment: @Joey That's a sign of the lack of expressiveness in HTML, something being addressed by HTML5, and also often a lack of experience with CSS selectors, rather than an argument for special casing those two attributes.