# Unicorn can't find bundler using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, unicorn

I can't seem to get bundler to work with unicorn on deploy. I am using capistrano to deploy.

Looking at the unicorn log while deploying, I get the following errors:

```
/home/deployer/apps/my-app/releases/20130417145122)
I, [2013-04-17T14:53:04.982369 #6565]  INFO -- : forked child re-executing...
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /home/deployer/apps/my-app/releases/20130417020329/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
  from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
  from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
  from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
E, [2013-04-17T14:53:05.054942 #18166] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6565 exit 1> exec()-ed
```

Capistrano is cleaning up the last 5 releases of the app, and I see that bundler is trying to access a non-existent (last deleted) release.

I found this code that I placed into unicorn.rb.erb, but it didn't help (I tried hardcoding it as well):
http://davidvollbracht.com/blog/headachenewunicorn-capistrano-bundler-usr2

```
before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "<%= current_path %>/Gemfile"
end
```

After deploying my code, I've started and stopped NGINX, and started and stopped unicorn, but I get the same issue.

My original post on stack overflow is here, but I thought it had to do with the asset pipeline: [Asset pipeline not working in rails production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052084/asset-pipeline-not-working-in-rails-production-environment)

Thoughts?

Here's my unicorn.rb.erb file:

```
working_directory "<%= current_path %>"
pid "<%= unicorn_pid %>"
stderr_path "<%= unicorn_log %>"
stdout_path "<%= unicorn_log %>"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.<%= application %>.sock"
worker_processes <%= unicorn_workers %>
timeout 30

preload_app true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "<%= current_path %>/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Disconnect since the database connection will not carry over
  if defined? ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  # Quit the old unicorn process
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Start up the database connection again in the worker
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Here's my unicorn_init.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/my-app/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig USR2 && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the bundler install task for Capistrano if you aren't already: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb

The gem dependencies will be automatically installed in the /home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle directory at deploy time, and persist across releases.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, where using the "before_fork" block to set BUNDLE_GEMFILE didn't actually solve the problem, despite the Rails app thinking ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] was pointing to the Gemfile through the current/ symlink.

I still don't entirely understand it, but we were using RVM in production as well. I managed to fix the problem by adding:

```
export BUNDLE_GEMFILE="${APP_ROOT}/Gemfile"
```

to the init script. Does that solve your problem?