# Listener for HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

Is there a command like

```
sass --watch style.sass:style.css
```

for HAML?

I really like writing my code in haml, but every time I save my haml file, I must type in

```
haml index.haml index.html
```

So is there anything like a viewer, which automatically converts the file, when I save the haml file.

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: hmmm that's weird, I usually use `haml-rails` gem, I change haml files and I see changes just reloading page.

Comment: okay, I must say, I don't use haml together with ruby on rails, I just opened my editor and type in some text like "%p hi" and than convert it. I have no idea how I use it "correctly" to date, but I'm learning it.

Comment: oh ok, I suggest that because your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pretty easy option is to set up `guard`. See the [guard-haml](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml) tool.

If you don't want to set it up, you can try [liveReload](http://livereload.com/) for a more graphical and interactive setup.

Related to @juanpastas' comment...if you're using Rails the normal way (from v3.1 onward), you get HAML "for free" via [the assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). You just need to [include HAML gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99211/how-do-i-get-haml-to-work-with-rails).